# How to run code on final iteration on a cursor

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database-cursor

I have a repository function, *GetDocs()*, that returns a MongoDB cursor.

Where I call *GetDocs* I iterate over the cursor and on every fifth iteration I call *SetLastId()*.

**Question:** How do I identify when I am processing the last element of the cursor so I can call *SetLastId()* before exiting the loop?

```
public async Task GetDocs(string id, Func<Model, Task> processor)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter;
            var sort = Builders<Model>.Sort;
            using (var cursor = await Coll.Find(filter.Eq(f => f.id, id)).ToCursorAsync())
            {
                foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                {                    
                    await processor(doc);
                }
            }
        }
```

.

```
    using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(context.connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        int counter = 0;

        await repo.GetDocs(context.Id, async (doc) =>
         {
             if (counter % 5 == 0)
             {
                var success = await SetLastId(doc.Id);
             }
             counter++;
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? Basically, the loop will store the previous document in memory and process it on the next iteration. That way, once it exits the loop, it has the "last doc" to hand, and can flag it as such to the processor.

```
public async Task GetDocs(string id, Func<Model, bool, Task> processor)
{
    var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter;
    var sort = Builders<Model>.Sort;
    using (var cursor = await Coll.Find(filter.Eq(f => f.id, id)).ToCursorAsync())
    {
        Model previousDoc = null;
        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
        {
            if (previousDoc != null)
            {
                await processor(previousDoc, false);
            }
            previousDoc = doc;
        }
        if (previousDoc != null)
        {
            await processor(previousDoc, true);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also wrap it up into a reusable method that works with any IEnumerable (I've used [ValueTuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) here, but you could make your own type if you can't use them):

```
public static IEnumerable<(T Model, bool IsLast)> Map<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    T prevModel = default(T);
    bool isFirst = true;
    foreach (var model in items)
    {
        if (!isFirst)
        {
            yield return (prevModel, false);
        }
        else
        {
            isFirst = false;
        }
        prevModel = model;
    }

    if (!isFirst)
    {
        yield return (prevModel, true);
    }
}


public async Task GetDocs(string id, Func<Model, bool, Task> processor)
{
    var filter = Builders<Model>.Filter;
    var sort = Builders<Model>.Sort;
    using (var cursor = await Coll.Find(filter.Eq(f => f.id, id)).ToCursorAsync())
    {
        foreach (var docWrapper in Map(cursor.Current))
        {
            await processor(docWrapper.Model, docWrapper.IsLast);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you somehow want to put "ObjectId lastId = ObjectId.Empty;" outside the "repo.GetDocs" loop. 
I have of cause thought about just assigning "doc.Id" to a variable outside the loop, but my code would be so much much cleaner if I do not have to do this.

Comment: I had been thinking of how I'd do it in wrong piece of code it seems. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks